# Trace exact column during error while debugging stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I work on support for a large and complex project based on SQL Server 2005. It consists of more than 800 stored procedures and 1000 tables. Most stored procedures contain 2000+ lines and some have 10000+ lines of code. Each table contain more than 200 columns.

Most of the stored procedures contain while loops, cursors, while loop in another cursor loop which is enormously complex. We use many temp tables, table variables with more than 200 columns

I face difficulty when there is any error occurs. The most frequent errors are like below:

> String or binary data would be truncated

or

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

and so on

It is extremely difficult to find out which column is occurring error. As the above error messages just show the error but not the actual column.

Since there are more than 200 columns it has become a daunting task to find out the culprit. I have to comment/hardcode few columns and need to check if error is occurring or not.

Please find an example below for better understanding of my issue:

```
DECLARE @tablevar TABLE( Column1 int, column2 char(2),column char(6),.....
......,**Column137 char(7)**,..............column199 char(7), column(200) char(6))

......some code...

--while loop

while i < count  

Begin

--some code

Insert into @tablevar(Column1, column2,column3,.....
.....,**column137**...............column199, column200))

select t1.OthertableColumn1,t1.OthertableColumn2,t2.OthertableColumn3,t3.Othertablecolumn4,...
....,**t2.OthertableColumn137**,....

so on..........

t2.Column200)

from OtherTable t1 with (nolock)

LEFT JOIN OtherTable2 t2 with (nolock) on t1.col1 = t2.Column1

LEFT JOIN OtherTable3 t3 with (nolock) on t3.col1 = t2.Column1

LEFT JOIN OtherTable4 t4 with (nolock) on t4.col1 = t3.Column1

LEFT JOIN OtherTable5 t5 with (nolock) on t5.col1 = t1.Column1

LEFT JOIN OtherTable6 t6 with (nolock) on t6.col2 = t4.Column1

....
End
```

The actual error is occurring with the column Column137. The size of the column column137 of the table variable @tablevar is 7 characters but it is inserting more characters, for e.g. 'sample data'. So throwing the error - String or binary data would be truncated.

How do I identify this Column137 out of that large number of 200 columns? Is there any way of finding the specific column name where the error is occurring?

Is there any shortcut/simple way to find out exact column?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's time to give more votes to the connect item: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name

Comment: As the above comment hints, this particular class of error are notoriously challenging.  But voting is closed on the item...

Comment: @Stan - What do you mean "voting is closed"? It is still active. You need to be signed in to vote.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I am logged in to their site and receive the message "Voting is no longer enabled on this item".  Attempts to access the older duplicate throw a site error.  Fun observation: they accepted the enhancement request in 2008....

Comment: @Stan - Strange. I had already voted for it but it lets me change from upvote to downvote and back again.

Comment: Thanks James for sharing the link. I will try to use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your not going to like this answer.  It involves work and may not be suitable for production (you might have to enable it only for troubleshooting).

You do not indicate the source of the data, but lets assume SQL Parameters, and a nice name like `@pForColumn137`

Both these options are given as examples that benefit only the current column being discussed -- a full solution would require similar code for each column (yes, yuck)

Option 1: change the insert to be `SUBSTRING(@pForColumn137,1,7)`

...but this just avoids the error and silently truncates

Option 2: add

```
IF @LEN(@pForColumn137) > 7 RAISERROR ('Column 137 value is too long!',16,1);
```

...but this throws a hard error that at least is somewhat more specific.  Getting a nicer message is possible - use a local @MSG VARCHAR variable and build the message to passe to `RAISERROR`.

To test the `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar`, you would code something like below...here pretending @ForColumn137 is INT...which has a possible scale of 10 and will not always fit into VARCHAR(7)

```
IF @LEN(LTRIM(STR(@pForColumn137))) > 7 RAISERROR('Value for Column 137 requires too many characters')
```

or if you like fancy math and really are dealing with integers

```
IF CEILING(LOG10(@pForColumn137) ) > 7 RAISERROR('Value for Column 137 requires too many characters')
```

WARNING: Both these numeric to string test get more complicated if decimal values are included.  STR takes two optional arguments you can sort of use if you know the significant number of decimals.  The LOG10 trick is not applicable

Good luck.

Comment: My solution here would be to do BOTH - the block of IF....RAISERROR would be conditional, enabled only in DEV builds so that the developer would be more likely to catch their errors.   The silent truncation would be in all builds to prevent errors -- if you are comfortable with the potential 'data loss'.

Comment: Thanks Stan for your reply. Your solution is helpful in some scenarios.